# How to calculate the distance between two GMMs in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, statistics, computer-vision

I am training two GMMs in OpenCV, each with 4 components. One GMM is trained using all points from the foreground of an image and another is trained using all points in the background. I want to find out how close are the two GMMs to each other in order to get an idea on how close are the background colours to the foreground colours.

Any ideas on how I can go about this problem? The popular distance measures I see (KL, Mahalanobis etc.) are for single variable normal distributions. How can I extend this to GMMs trained on RGB values of each pixel?

Comment: Maybe you could see in your training set, which proportion of the foreground is classified as background and the other way around.
You could observe the probability ratio when the data is classified correctly.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using opencv [backgroundsubtractormog2](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2)? However, you could go through the code or the relative paper (linked in the doc) to see how it's done.

Comment: @Miki: I just want to get an idea of the color separability in the background and foreground (and not remove/subtract the background itself). How will what you suggested help?

Comment: @AdMor: Could you please be a little more clear. I didn't understand your suggestion. What is this probability ratio you speak off? The suggestion is to apply the GMMs on the training pixels and see how correctly are the GMMs classifying? How will this help in finding the distance between the two GMMs?

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook : I was thinking about something similar to the likelihood ratio (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test , see simple vs simple). You don't get THE distance between the GMM but you get an estimation of the margin between the foreground and background classes. Then if you have 10 different models, you can select the one with the biggest margin.

Comment: @Admor That's the thing, I want the distance as a measure of how good is the color difference between the background and the foreground and not to actually separate the two. So, I am sort of looking for a metric that can help me put a number to the difference between the background and the foreground.

Comment: Probably you already know [this paper](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/pubs/JenECJ07-gmmdist.pdf) and [this paper](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDEQFjABahUKEwjPiuaBho7HAhVDOxQKHcsyDno&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdme.rwth-aachen.de%2Fen%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Ffile_upload%2Fpublications%2FBeecks_ICCV2011.pdf&ei=k_a_VY_1M8P2UMvluNAH&usg=AFQjCNF3vtD8igT4ErWh1kfPVutFVy5wGQ&sig2=FH2xxvVe_7LjG_4gcd758g&bvm=bv.99261572,d.bGg&cad=rja). Well, just in case...

Answer (score 1):

Because gaussian mixture model consists of a set of weighted gaussians, you can find distance between centers of nearest gaussuans of two models. But this is not absolutely correct approach, because of probabilistic nature of model. It'll be much better to look at probabilities of both models for given value.

Comment: I will give this a try, but I am hoping I could come up with a better approximation of the distance.